# What is knitting in Winter Bash 2018?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I found something related to knitting.

What is it exactly? What we can do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

It's (almost) winter on the Northern hemisphere, the coldest period of the year and associated with knitwear, especially [Christmas sweaters](https://www.buzzfeed.com/betsydickerson/the-best-ugly-christmas-sweaters-you-can-get).

With this tool (available after clicking the 'Start Knitting' button), you can 'draw' your own creations and post them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/295232). There might be a challenge involved (maybe the top x answers get a knitted sweater with their design), maybe it's just a fun topic. We'll know more within a few weeks ...

Comment: I'm not sure it's a challenge. It was posted by a regular user.

Comment: Also that post doesn't have 'feature' tag which indicates the event officially created by SE admin/mods.

Comment: Maybe clarify that you need to click the "Start Knitting" button to activate the editor. This was not entirely clear to me when I clicked it.

Comment: Why say "few weeks" when we have a definitive timeline? It's 6-8 weeks, always.